# Multiple input and multiple output with onclick eventlistener in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, web

Want to ask :
For example , i have multiple button and when i click on anyone, the value will be shown at the result textbox and the input textbox will back to 0 , need help on check my code :

```
document.getElementById("plusthevalue").addEventListener('click',function plus()
{
    var inputvalue = document.getElementById("Input");
    var resultvalue = document.getElementById("Result");
    document.write("Result").value = inputvalue + resultvalue;
    document.write("Input").value ="0";

});
```

and, if i want to write a single statement that can include all the button and will display the output depend on the button, how would the code will be?
p/s: i know i can hardwork until i code function for every button but that would be very messy , i want to include all :(

Comment: It's a little hard to understand what you're trying to achieve, but language barriers aside -- lets give this a shot! I recommend looping through all of the buttons you need the `addEventListener` attached to. This will allow you to run the above function for each of the buttons without having to create separate event listeners for each of them.

Comment: Btw, why aren't you using jQuery to achieve this more easily? I only say this because you have this tagged as `jQuery`, but are doing it natively: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Comment: @adamj hmm what i want to achive is : i have button a, b, c. If i click on button a, the textbox will display a, if i click on a then b then c, the textbox will display abc. I know that i can do one function for each button, but it is anyway to combine it and done it with addeventlistener?

Comment: i haven learn the jQuery and so i use javascript

Answer (score 1):

You can assign all your buttons a certain class, then use `document.querySelectorAll('.myclass')` to grab all of them. Then you can loop through the results to add the event listener to each of them.

Example:

```
var myButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.myclass');
for (i = 0; i < myButtons.length; ++i) {
    myButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll for more info about `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: how to assign button to a certain class?

Comment: <button class="myclass">My Button</button>

Comment: ok...but how to assign some value to textbox while some button is click? i already done some coding but it seem not working :(

Comment: If you need to get properties of the button that a user clicked, use the "e" parameter of the callback. Put console.log(e) in the listener so you can see the properties of the event. e.target will store the properties of the event target which in this case is the button being pressed. For example, you could use e.target.id to get the button id, or e.target.innerText to get the button's text. Then you could do something like `var resultvalue = document.getElementById("Result"); resultvalue.value += e.target.innerText;` to add the button's text to the input box.

Comment: can give some link to example coding?

Comment: my question is like this :

Comment: Use a single JavaScript statement to add the click event listener to each of the number
buttons so that when a number button is clicked, the number will be concatenated to the
numbers that are already in the input text box that has the id “txtInput”. However, if the
number in the input text box “txtInput” is 0 then the number 0 will be replaced by the
number that the user just clicked.

p/s : I need something like that? or need different style? i m currently stucked on this exercise for long time yet can't solve :(

Comment: Each button will need to have an event listener attached to it so this is not possible in a 'single statement'. But if a single statement is a requirement, maybe you could put all the buttons inside a div and add an event listener to the div which will figure out which button was clicked, etc.

Comment: so if each button have single event listener...what the code should be ?

Comment: document.getElementById('btnNumber1').addEventListener('click',function()
 {
  txtInput = document.getElementById('txtInput');
  txtInput.value = txtInput.value + '1';
 });




i write this but seem not working..can help me check?